# Remove curly brackets _completely_ to map a function to the elements of a list

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, function-construction

Most list manipulations can be done with `Flatten`, `Partition` and `Take`. I didn't managed to use them for my need: I'd like to know if there is nice solution to map a function of several variables to a list, and other variables. For examples, given:

```
f[a_,b_,c_]=a+b+c;
```

and

```
list={2,3};
```

I'd like to calculate `f[a,2,3]`

Of course, I could use

```
f[a,list[[1]],list[[2]]]
```

but I'm looking for something a bit more general, such as

```
f[a,MysteriousFunction[list]]
(* wished output: a+1+2 *)
```

Does such a MysteriousFunction exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
f[a_, b_, c_] = a + b + c;
list = {2, 3};
f[a, Sequence @@ list]
(* 5 + a *)
```

Comment: (thanks!) To go slightly further: I'd like to replace something in list before; `f[a, Sequence@@list/. 2->4]` doesn't work, but `f[a, Sequence@@Sequence@@list/. 2->4]` does. There's probably a simpler way but I didn't find it yet.

Comment: minor question: is there a reason to use `Sequence@@...` rather than `Sequence[...]`?

Comment: @anderstood Nope. Just old vices

Comment: @anderstood `f[a, Sequence @@ (list /. 2 -> 4)]`

Comment: Wow. I had tried with curly brackets... I did not know parenthesis were useful elsewhere than in infix notations in Mathematica.

Comment: @anderstood You need `@@` to replace the head `List` by `Sequence`  ... `Sequence[{1, 2}] != Sequence @@ {1, 2}`